# Ansible - Replace values in a dictionary by looping through another dictionary

Tags: dictionary, replace, ansible, key-value

I have two dictionaries as below

```
"fictional_characters": {
   "male": [
      "Donkey",
      "Humpty",
      "Piranha"
   ],
   "female": [
      "Fiona",
      "Kitty_Softpaws",
      "Diane_Foxington"
   ]
}
```

And

```
"movie_names": {
   "Donkey": "Shrek",
   "Humpty": "Puss_in_Boots",
   "Piranha": "The_Bad_Guys",
   "Fiona": "Shrek",
   "Kitty_Softpaws": "Puss_in_Boots",
   "Diane_Foxingtin": "The_Bad_Guys"
}
```

I would like to change the dictionary values in "fictional_characters" to the values in "movie_names", e.g.

```
"fictional_characters": {
   "male": [
      "Shrek",
      "Puss_in_Boots",
      "The_Bad_Guys"
   ],
   "female": [
      "Shrek",
      "Puss_in_Boots",
      "The_Bad_Guys"
   ]
}
```

I started by converting the "fictional_characters" dictionary into a list

```
- name: Convert fictional_characters to a list
  set_fact:
    fictional_characters_list: "{{fictional_characters | dict2items }}"
```

That gave me

```
"fictional_characters_list": [
  {
    "key": "male",
    "value": [
      "Donkey",
      "Humpty",
      "Piranha"
    ],
  },
    "key": "female",
    "value": [
      "Fiona",
      "Kitty_Softpaws",
      "Diane_Foxington"
    ]
  }
]
```

Next, some Jinja

```
- name: Using Jinja to swap dict values
  set_fact:
    fict_char_movies: |
      {% for e in fictional_characters_list %}
      {{ e.key }}:
      {% for char in e.value %}
      {% if char in movie_names %}
        - {{ movie_names[char]|split(',') %}
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}

- name: Print the result
  debug:
    msg: "{{ fict_char_movies | from_yaml }}"
```

the above returns the following result

```
"male": [
  [
    "Shrek"
  ],
  [
    "Puss_in_Boots"
  ],
  [
    "The_Bad_Guys"
  ],
"female": [
  [
    "Shrek"
  ],
  [
    "Puss_in_Boots"
  ],
  [
    "The_Bad_Guys"
  ]
]
```

How do I get rid of this nested list so that I get the below structure ?

```
"fictional_characters": {
   "male": [
      "Shrek",
      "Puss_in_Boots",
      "The_Bad_Guys"
   ],
   "female": [
      "Shrek",
      "Puss_in_Boots",
      "The_Bad_Guys"
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declarations below

```yaml
  fict_char_movies_str: |
    {% for k,v in fictional_characters.items() %}
    {{ k }}:
    {% for char in v %}
    {% if char in movie_names %}
      - {{ movie_names[char] }}
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
  fict_char_movies: "{{ fict_char_movies_str|from_yaml }}"
```

---

The template can be simplified

```yaml
    fict_char_movies_str: |
      {% for k,v in fictional_characters.items() %}
      {{ k }}:
        {{ v|map('extract', movie_names) }}
      {% endfor %}
```

---

give what you want

```yaml
  fict_char_movies:
    female:
    - Shrek
    - Puss_in_Boots
    - The_Bad_Guys
    male:
    - Shrek
    - Puss_in_Boots
    - The_Bad_Guys
```

---

If you want to iterate *set_fact* the task below gives the same result

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        fict_char_movies: "{{ fict_char_movies|d({})|combine(_dict|from_yaml) }}"
      loop: "{{ fictional_characters|dict2items }}"
      vars:
        _dict: "{ {{ item.key }}: {{ item.value|map('extract', movie_names) }} }"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    fictional_characters:
      female:
      - Fiona
      - Kitty_Softpaws
      - Diane_Foxington
      male:
      - Donkey
      - Humpty
      - Piranha

    movie_names:
      Diane_Foxington: The_Bad_Guys
      Donkey: Shrek
      Fiona: Shrek
      Humpty: Puss_in_Boots
      Kitty_Softpaws: Puss_in_Boots
      Piranha: The_Bad_Guys

    fict_char_movies_str: |
      {% for k,v in fictional_characters.items() %}
      {{ k }}:
        {{ v|map('extract', movie_names) }}
      {% endfor %}
    fict_char_movies: "{{ fict_char_movies_str|from_yaml }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: fict_char_movies
```

Comment: Thanks @Vladimir,
I had also tried the {% for k,v in fictional_characters.items() %} approach but it was giving me the same results.
In both options, i was using " |split(',') " so i was creating the issue that i needed to resolve myself.
Thanks again !

Comment: The template can be simplified. I updated the answer. You're welcome.

Comment: I added a simplified iteration of *set_fact*.

Comment: Great and concise answer and it's worth it to upvote!

Answer (score 1):

Vladimir's solution is probably cleaner, but it's also possible to get to the same place without using a Jinja template.  For example, we can write:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:

    fictional_characters:
      male:
        - Donkey
        - Humpty
        - Piranha
      female:
        - Fiona
        - Kitty_Softpaws
        - Diane_Foxington
        - Meilin_Lee

    movie_names:
      Donkey: Shrek
      Humpty: Puss_in_Boots
      Piranha: The_Bad_Guys
      Fiona: Shrek
      Kitty_Softpaws: Puss_in_Boots
      Diane_Foxington: The_Bad_Guys
      Meilin_Lee: Turning_Red

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        new_fictional_characters: >-
          {{
            new_fictional_characters|combine(
              {
                'male': item.0|ternary(new_fictional_characters.male + [movie_names[item.0]], new_fictional_characters.male),
                'female': item.1|ternary(new_fictional_characters.female + [movie_names[item.1]], new_fictional_characters.female),
              }
            )
          }}
      loop: >-
        {{ fictional_characters.male|zip_longest(fictional_characters.female) }}
      vars:
        new_fictional_characters:
          male: []
          female: []

    - set_fact:
        fictional_characters: "{{ new_fictional_characters }}"

    - debug:
        var: fictional_characters
```

Note that I've added an additional character here to demonstrate that this works when the lists are of different lengths. Running this produces:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=['Donkey', 'Fiona'])
ok: [localhost] => (item=['Humpty', 'Kitty_Softpaws'])
ok: [localhost] => (item=['Piranha', 'Diane_Foxington'])
ok: [localhost] => (item=[None, 'Meilin_Lee'])

TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "fictional_characters": {
        "female": [
            "Shrek",
            "Puss_in_Boots",
            "The_Bad_Guys",
            "Turning_Red"
        ],
        "male": [
            "Shrek",
            "Puss_in_Boots",
            "The_Bad_Guys"
        ]
    }
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

An even simpler solution is to drop the following into `filter_plugins/swap_names.py`:

```
def filter_swap_names(val, name_map):
    return {k: [name_map[name] for name in v] for k, v in val.items()}


class FilterModule:
    def filters(self):
        return dict(swap_names=filter_swap_names)
```

And then write the playbook like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:

    fictional_characters:
      male:
        - Donkey
        - Humpty
        - Piranha
      female:
        - Fiona
        - Kitty_Softpaws
        - Diane_Foxington
        - Meilin_Lee

    movie_names:
      Donkey: Shrek
      Humpty: Puss_in_Boots
      Piranha: The_Bad_Guys
      Fiona: Shrek
      Kitty_Softpaws: Puss_in_Boots
      Diane_Foxington: The_Bad_Guys
      Meilin_Lee: Turning_Red

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        fictional_characters: "{{ fictional_characters|swap_names(movie_names) }}"

    - debug:
        var: fictional_characters
```

Comment: Upvote! This is a great answer as well, specially in the filer_plugins part!

Comment: Thanks @larsks,
I'm not familiar with the "filter_plugins/swap_names.py" method but it looks good. I'll definitely be using this in the future

Comment: The documentation on [writing your own filter plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#filter-plugins) might be helpful. Generally, I think this is a much better way to handle complex transformations of your data.